# Migration from WordPress blog to React

Tags: wordpress

I need to migrate WP blog (Avada theme) to shiny new website built in React. But all the blog posts are filled with code from Fusion page builder that comes with Avada [fusion_text], [fusion_builder_column][fusion_builder_row]... What can I do?

How can I export posts without Avada junk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress API to get all posts. check [Sourcing from WordPress](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/sourcing-from-wordpress/)

Comment: The problem is, posts are infected with Avada page builder specific tags, like [fusion_text], [fusion_builder_column]... and there are more than 2000 posts